# Handling a post preview

Tags: php, html

I have created a post input form and now I have the requirement that it must support a preview and work without Javascript.

Here's my predicament. I can handle the preview request on the server side but the headers will have already been sent, so I am unable to send a redirect. The header, sidebar and footer of the page have already been rendered, so displaying the preview of a new page inside the page will be ugly. That leaves me with opening a new window.

How can I open a new window and at the same time send the POST request? Is it even possible?

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
<div>
<a href="post review link" target="_blank">Preview</a>
<input type="hidden" name="preview" value="dopreview" />
</div>
```

I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I open a new window and at the same time send the POST
>   request? Is it even possible?

Without javascript, no.

Just send to the same page, and detect in PHP when you have the preview POST set.

```
<input type='submit' name='preview' value='Preview' />

//In PHP code
if (isset($_POST['preview']))
{
     //Show preview to user
}
```

Comment: Detecting the preview is the easy part. Doing it this way leaves me with nowhere to display the preview since it will be displayed within an existing page.

Comment: You'll just have to conditionally modify your page, by adding another div, where you show the preview. With the "if" power, I don't understand what's hard about it.

Comment: picture a page with header sidebar and footer, then displaying the preview of another page within that content area. It isn't going to work. I must either use the full display area of the page or open in a new window. Since I have no way of removing the existing content a new window is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of doing it with javascript.

```
function Validate()
{
    document.previewform.submit();
    setTimeout("doPost()", 10);

    return false;
}

function doPost()
{
    document.mainform.submit();
}
```

The first function does your form post that open the new window preview, then queues the other form to post in the background window.